# How to handle back arrows, End and Home keys in a read prompt

Tags: shell-script, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, readline, read

Using `read` and by typing `word followed by the left arrow <kbd>←</kbd>, one get

```
 $ read
 word^[[D
```

The same goes for the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys that lead to `^[[H` and `^[[F` respectively.

How can I handle those characters, so that I go backward with the left arrow <kbd>←</kbd>`, at the beginning and end of what has been written with <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline` library usually handles this, and `inputrc` tells you which codes are emitted. Forcing the shell into interactive mode should enable these features. `curses` is a library that does the full support for moving the cursor around (if you want a text editor or something).

But ultimately, you have to remember, that the terminal is the *sender* and *receiver* of input/output. So... printing a control sequence that moves the cursor should move the cursor, so you can always write anything to any position on the screen. Terminals differ somewhat in control sequences they respond to, but check out [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) for the reference.